# CSS Truncate text within a flexbox parent with flex-direction column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

How can I truncate the text below? The min-width: 0; hack doesn't work when flex-direction is set to column. Neither does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514597/how-to-truncate-string-inside-a-direction-column-flexbox-child).

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you give `align-items: center` the `text` overflows the `parent` and the width is not *constrained* and so *ellipsis* will not appear.

If you remove `align-items: center` it works because `align-items: stretch` is the default - but the image get *stretched* out now:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution**

Add `width: 100%` to the `text` - see demo below:

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
  </div>
</div>
```

> The min-width: 0; hack doesn't work when flex-direction is set to
>   column.

Note that in `min-width: 0` if for overriding the the flex item width as it is *auto* in the row direction (for *column* direction you use `min-height`). See example below for `min-height: 0` used in a *column flexbox*:

- [Flexbox resize and scrollable overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303538/flexbox-resize-and-scrollable-overflow)

Comment: I had a truncated text nested in a column `flexbox`. I added `width: 100%` to every ancestors in the tree and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the   `display: flex;` in Parent Class into `display: block` and add to img tag the following

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  align-items: center; 
  width: 300px;
}

img{  
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Although this works as well, I've accepted kukkuz answer because it uses flexbox.

Comment: No worries , Glad to help !